# JQuery Not Working After Adding PHP to HTML file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm building a webpage with fully functioning jquery (for form submit). Since adding php to the file to pull user data into the form, the jQuery has stopped working and the function triggered on button click is no longer called.

Console now returns this when function is called.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):255)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Here is the php included at top of file:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['p'])){
  $product_code = $_GET['p'];
 }
 else{
  $product_code = "beans";
 }

 if(isset($_GET['name'])){
  $name = $_GET['name'];
 }
 else{
  $name = "";
 }

if(isset($_GET['email'])){
 $email = $_GET['email'];
}
else{
 $email = "";
 }

 switch ($product_code) {
   case "beans":
    $product = "Baked Beans";
    break;
  case "peas":
    $product = "Green Peas";
    break;
 ?>
```

Throughout the `body`, `<?php echo $product; ?>` is inserted in several places.

Here is the jQuery, placed before `</head>` tag (now not working):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form-cont-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var review = $('textarea#review').val();
// ***line 255 below***
    if (review.length < 1) {
      $("textarea").addClass("error");
      alert("Oops! Looks like your review is empty..\n\nPlease write review before pressing 'Continue'.");
      return false;
    } else if (review.length < 50) {
      $("textarea").addClass("error");
      alert("Oops! Your review should contain at least 50 characters");
      return false;
    }
    $(".act-1,.act-1-btn").fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(".act-2,.act-2-btn").fadeIn();
    });
    return false;
  });
  $("textarea").click(function(e) {
    $("textarea").removeClass("error");
  });
  var form = document.getElementById('form-id');
  $("#form-btn").click(function() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    if (name.length < 1) {
      $("#name").addClass("error");
      alert("Oops! Looks like your name is empty..\n\nPlease enter your name before pressing 'Enter Now'.");
      return false;
    } else if (name.length < 2) {
      $("#name").addClass("error");
      alert("Oops! Please enter a valid name, an alias is fine");
      return false;
    }
    var email = $('#email').val();
    if (email.length < 1) {
      $("#email").addClass("error");
      alert("Oops! Looks like your email is empty..\n\nPlease enter your email before pressing 'Enter Now'.");
      return false;
    } else if ((email.indexOf('@') == -1) || (email.indexOf('.') == -1) || (email.length < 7)) {
      alert(email.indexOf('@'));
      alert(email.indexOf('.'));
      alert(email.length);
      $("#email").addClass("error");
      alert("Oops! Looks like your email is invalid..\n\nPlease enter a valid email before pressing 'Enter Now'.");
      return false;
    }
    alert('submitting');
    $('this').submit();
  });

  $("#name").click(function(e) {
    $("#name").removeClass("error");
  });
  $("#email").click(function(e) {
    $("#email").removeClass("error");
  });
  $('#entry-focus').change(function() {
    var selected_product = $('#entry-focus').find(":selected").text();
    $('form').find("textarea").each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).attr("placeholder", "Comment on your experience with " + selected_product);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the html of the form:

```
<div class="row form-holder">
                <h2 class="upper spaced">Enter your review for a chance to Win</h2>
                <form id="form-id" action="connect/csv.php" method="POST">

                        <!--ACT 1-->
                        <div class="row act-1 grid">
                            <div class="row">

                                <span class="form-label">Product:</span>

                                <h2 class="upper heavy spaced bigger text-left" align="left"><? echo $product; ?></h2>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product_code; ?>" id="product" name="product">

                        </div>
                        <div class="row"><span class="form-label">Review:</span><textarea type="textarea" value="" id="entry-focus" name="review" form="form-id" placeholder="Comment on your experience with <? echo $product; ?>"></textarea></div>
                        </div>

                        <button id="form-cont-btn" class="btn-action widest act-1-btn">Continue</button>

                        <!--END ACT 1-->
                        <!--ACT 2-->
                        <div class="row act-2">
                        <div class="row"><span class="form-label">Name:</span><input type="text" value="<? echo $name; ?>" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"></div>
                        <div class="row"><span class="form-label">Email:</span><input type="text" value="<? echo $email; ?>" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Valid Email"></div>
                        </div>

                        <button id="form-btn" class="btn-action widest act-2-btn">Enter Now</button>
                        <input type="hidden" value="set" name="submit">

                        <!--END ACT 2-->
                </form>
            </div>
```

After several attempts to resolve this with `$.noConflict();` and changing `$` to `jQuery`, the console still throws the same error.

Any ideas on what may cause the jQuery to stop working?

Comment: Please click `<>` and create a [mcve] with RENDERED html. Please click TIDY before saving

Comment: What's the error in console?

Comment: use on method : most probably your elements are loading after the jquery. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_on

Comment: view the generated html (right click>view source) and edit you question with the javascript at line 255 (as indicated by the error message). Also, unless the page is massive, it would help to add the complete generated html to your question

Comment: Also, just a quick note as you are new here, when asking a question make sure you are immediately available to respond to comments, because most views happen within a few minutes of posting, and people will forget all about your question very quickly.

Comment: Post the generated HTML, please.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ html now added

Comment: @Steve line 255 now marked

Comment: In your HTML, there's no textarea with the id `review`. So it's normal that the variable `review` is `undefined` and the property `length` is inexistant.

Comment: @MilanChheda error listed above: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined... (*line 255 - marked in js)

Comment: As mentioned by @ADreNaLiNe-DJ the only textarea in the form has an id of `entry-focus` yet your jquery targets an id of `review`. This doesnt exist

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Thanks - this was the issue - the ID of textarea element had been changed during previous amend. I feel silly for overlooking that issue. Appreciate all the help I've received here and will endeavour to improve question markup and accuracy in future (without oversight!).

Comment: @CJanus You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The line `254` is `var review = $('textarea#review').val();`, which means that you want to get the value of a `textarea` with the `id` set to `review`.

In the generated HTML, the textarea have an `id` set to `entry-focus`. So, your code on line `254` does not get anything but `undefined`. This why you have the error message at line `255`.

To get the right content, you have to replace the line `254` with this code:

```
var review = $('textarea#entry-focus').val();
```

Or set the `id` of your textarea to `review`.